# Is there a term for "a node and its ancestors"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm trying refer to *a node and its ancestors*, **but not its descendants**. There's a decent discussion about this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257325/me-and-my-ancestors-single-word) but most of the suggestions would include descendants (`kin`, `lineage`, `blood-line`, etc.)

Typically I'd just say "a node and its ancestors" but I'm trying name this variable in a computer program and I can't come up with anything good.

Comment: I don't know if it is a widely-used term in graph/tree theory, but I would call it *ascendants*.

Comment: I think the term parent and child node are more common.

Comment: Hmm, a node's "descendants" typically would not include the node itself. I assume "ascendants" would also exclude the subject node, no?

Comment: If this is in context of a tree - it's usually referred to as the (unique) path from a node $u$ to the root.